# where statement in linq to sql doesn't appear in the list

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework

I create a linq to sql in visual studio so i create a dbcontext object in my asp web form as you can see here :

```
 public AccidentCongress.dblinqtoDb.dbDataContext dbcontext = new dbDataContext();
        protected void BtnSend_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           if (dbcontext.tblUserInfos.??????)
        }
```

I need to select a row in `tblUserInfos` with where clause but the where clause doesn't in the list why ?

[image]

Comment: Do you have a `using System.Linq` statement in that file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have a `using System.Linq;` statement towards the top of that file.

Comment: I think all the given answers for this question are correct so far :-)

Comment: @Maarten Yes, but I was first.

Answer (score 1):

"Where" is an extension method which is declared in the System. Linq namespace,  so make sure you add "using System.Linq;" to the using section at the top of the cs file.

Answer (score 0):

Add reference to `System.Linq` or doesn't have using statement